# How to select special items of array for pagination using php?

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

For ex i have arrays like this

```
[0] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[1] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[2] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[3] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[4] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[5] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
```

Now i what i want is to show array data with pagination per page for ex 2.In some condition i cant use sql LIMIT query so i want to show like this. On Page number 1 show first 2 array

```
[0] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[1] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
```

On page 2 this should be like

```
[2] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[3] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
```

And on page 3

```
[4] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
[5] => Array{
  [name]=>ABC
}
```

How could i do this. Please help me
And note: cant use sql limit query

Comment: `array_slice/array_splice`

Comment: One `for` will do it . and you need to add show/hide section according to pagination button click

Comment: check bootstrap Datatables

Comment: Use `array_slice($array, ($pageNumber - 1) * 2, 2)`

Comment: @mohammad array_slice only extracts elements from single array . I need to extract arrays not elements

Comment: So you should loop through array and select target items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through array and in loop check index of item. If item index is in target range insert it in new variable.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$item){
    if ($key >= ($pageNumber-1)*2 && sizeof($newArr) < 2)
        @$newArr[] = $item;
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://ideone.com/e0WuFx)